# Join Query in Kibana KQL

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have three logs in ES like

```json
{"@timestamp":"2022-07-19T11:24:16.274073+05:30","log":{"level":200,"logger":"production","message":"BUY_ITEM1","context":{"user_id":31312},"datetime":"2022-07-19T11:24:16.274073+05:30","extra":{"ip":"127.0.0.1"}}}

{"@timestamp":"2022-07-19T11:24:16.274073+05:30","log":{"level":200,"logger":"production","message":"BUY_ITEM2","context":{"user_id":31312},"datetime":"2022-07-19T11:24:16.274073+05:30","extra":{"ip":"127.0.0.1"}}}

{"@timestamp":"2022-07-19T11:24:16.274073+05:30","log":{"level":200,"logger":"production","message":"CLICK_ITEM3","context":{"user_id":31312},"datetime":"2022-07-19T11:24:16.274073+05:30","extra":{"ip":"127.0.0.1"}}}
```

I can get the users who bought `Item1` by querying `log.message: "BUY_ITEM1"` in KQL in Kibana.

How can I get user_ids who have both `BUY_ITEM1` and `BUY_ITEM2` ?

Comment: KQL - 
log.message:(BUY_ITEM1 OR BUY_ITEM2)

Comment: @AshishTiwari will this show user_ids which have both BUY_ITEM1 and BUY_ITEM2 or does this show user_ids who have either one of them?

Comment: @Aishwarya, this is not possible in elasticsearch. But you could get close to it with aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

`Join` query as they exist in `SQL` are not really possible in `Elasticsearch`, they are [very limited](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html).

You will need to work around this issue.

## Work around

You could do an [aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) on `user_id` of all the product they bought.

```
GET /73031860/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "log.message.keyword": [
        "BUY_ITEM1",
        "BUY_ITEM2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "log.context.user_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "products": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "log.message.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you the following result

```json
{
...
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "users": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 31312,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "products": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "BUY_ITEM1",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "BUY_ITEM2",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I make this count to a graph in kibana?